# Measure on a generated $\sigma$-algebra generated alongside

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a family of $\cal{F}$ of subsets of a set $X$ and a function $\mu:\cal{F}\to[0,1]$.  Further assume that $\mu$ either is defined or can be extended on the intersections $A\cap B$ for $A, B\in\cal{F}$ such that it is consistent with $\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A\cap B)$.

A $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma(\cal{F})$, can be generated from $\cal{F}$ somewhat constructively [by a countable number of complement, union and intersection operations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_an_arbitrary_family)

Question: Can we say that $\mu$ can be extended "alongside" this construction to the whole of $\sigma(\cal{F})$? If not, what is missing or how does it fail? Does $X$ have to be countable, for example, or $\cal{F}$?

Comment: Could we not have a function with $\mu(\emptyset)\neq 0$? It would still satisfy the condition, since $\mu(A)+\mu(\emptyset)-\mu(\emptyset) = \mu(A) = \mu(A\cup\emptyset)$ as desired.

Comment: In order to write $\mu(A\cup B)$, you are also  assuming  that $A \cup B\in\cal{F}$ whenever $A, B\in\cal{F}$.

Comment: It is also missing some condition to ensure that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.